# How to read out /var/mail/username using php?

Tags: php, parsing, email

I'm sending local mail using the php mail() function like this:

```
mail('kramer65@localhost', 'THE SUBJECT', 'THE BODY', $headers);
```

When I do `cat /var/mail/kramer65` I get the following:

```
Received: by php0 (Postfix, from userid 1007)
    id 1A0A028DB7; Tue, 29 Apr 2014 11:00:48 +0200 (CEST)
To: kramer@localhost
Subject: THE SUBJECT
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:MyControllerTest.php
From: leenoash@bunq.com
Reply-To: leenoash@bunq.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.5.11-1~dotdeb.1
Message-Id: <20140429090048.1A0A028DB7@php0>
Date: Tue, 29 Apr 2014 11:00:48 +0200 (CEST)

THE BODY
```

To read that out from php I run the mail() function again and then I try to use the php mailparse extension and syslog the result like this

```
$output = mailparse_msg_parse_file('/var/mail/kramer65');
syslog(LOG_ERR, 'mailparse RESULT: ' . $output);
```

which results in: `Apr 29 11:00:48 php0 php: mailparse RESULT: Resource id #635`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? How can I read out the results from /var/mail/kramer65 from within php? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mailparse_msg_parse_file()` returns a MIME Resource, so that's why you're getting Resource id #635. You need to do something more to get the values you want out of the MIME Resource.

For example:

```
mailparse_msg_get_part_data ( resource $mimemail )
```

which gives you an array with the values you're looking for.